# Nested template class method syntax

Tags: c++, templates

If I have a class `A` that is templated on type `T`, and that class has a method `Foo` that is templated on type `U`

```
template <class T>
class A
{
public:
    template <class U>
    void Foo();
};
```

To define that function outside the class I need two template statements like so

```
template <class T>
template <class U>
void A<T>::Foo() {}            // this compiles
```

The following does not compile

```
template <class T, class U>
void A<T>::Foo() {}            // this does not compile
```

with the error

```
prog.cpp:10:6: error: no declaration matches ‘void A<T>::Foo()’
 void A<T>::Foo() {}
      ^~~~
prog.cpp:6:7: note: candidate is: ‘template<class T> template<class U> void A<T>::Foo()’
  void Foo();
       ^~~
prog.cpp:2:7: note: ‘class A<T>’ defined here
 class A
       ^
```

Is there a more terse/compact way to define both template types in a single statement like above?

Comment: I fear there is no other "compact" way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### C++20: Abbreviated function templates

> Is there a more terse/compact way to define both template types in a single statement like above?

As of C++20, you can make use of [abbreviated function templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Abbreviated_function_template), which allows declaring as well (later) defining function templates in a more compact manner. This approach, however, is restricted to type template parameters that can be inferred via template argument deduction, as the placeholder types (`auto` or  `SomeConcept auto`) must appear in the parameter list of an abbreviated function template declaration.

```
template <typename T>
struct A {
    void foo(auto);
};

template <typename T>
void A<T>::foo(auto) {}
```

Note that `void foo(auto)` is equivalent to `template<typename T> void foo(T)`, as the former declares a function template with a single (invented) template parameter corresponding to the single placeholder type. This means that mixing of the abbreviated function template syntax and the classic function template syntax for the same entity is allowed (e.g. using one syntax for declaring it and the other syntax for defining it):

```
template <typename T>
struct A {
    template <typename U>
    void foo(U);
};

template <typename T>
void A<T>::foo(auto) {}

template <typename T>
struct B {
    template <typename U>
    void foo(U, auto);
};

template <typename T>
void B<T>::foo(auto, auto) {}
```